# PHP is executing even though I don't want it to

Tags: html

So i need to create a email form my filename currently is test12.php and the script for emailing the form to my inbox is executing even though i have not pressed the submit button ! here is my code:

```
                <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
} 
?>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="test12.php" target="success" id="CmForm">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Enter your first name" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="Enter your email adress" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Enter your subject" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea class="text-area w-input"  name="comments" maxlength="5000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Write message" required="required"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input  class="submit-button w-button" data-wait="Please wait..." type="submit" value="Submit" onclick='$("#success").show()' onclick='$("#CmForm").hide()'>
 </td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
    }
    else {
        // form engine
        echo "<div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>";
    }
?>
```

Also i would like it to display the thank you message after i click submit and make the form itself dissapear! And also how can i make the text boxes smaller? They currently are huge!

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is not named correctly and thus the check for it fails. Better like this:

```
<input  class="submit-button w-button" data-wait="Please wait..." type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick='$("#success").show()' onclick='$("#CmForm").hide()'>
```

You also might want to move the check `if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {` in a way that the code for form submission is inside the else case of this condition, because otherwise you always get a "died" error message.

Use css to set the width of the textareas.

```
<style>
.text-area{width: 300px;}
</style>
```

The reorganized code looks like the following; however there is still room for improvement when handling errors which lead to the "died();" function.

```
if (!isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

?>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="test12.php" target="success" id="CmForm">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Enter your first name" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="Enter your email adress" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  class="text-area w-input" type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Enter your subject" required="required">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea class="text-area w-input"  name="comments" maxlength="5000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Write message" required="required"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input  class="submit-button w-button" data-wait="Please wait..." type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick='$("#success").show()' onclick='$("#CmForm").hide()'>
 </td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
    } else {
            // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
            $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
            $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

            function died($error) {
                // your error code can go here
                echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
                echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
                echo $error."<br /><br />";
                echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
                die();
            }


            // validation expected data exists
            if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
                !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
                died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
            }



            $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
            $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
            $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
            $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

            $error_message = "";
            $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

          if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }

            $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

          if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }

          if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }

          if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
          }

          if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($error_message);
          }

            $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


            function clean_string($string) {
              $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
              return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
            }



            $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

        // form engine
        echo "<div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>";
    }
?>
```

Further improvements to the code would be: Instead of die-ing in "died", show the form with prefilled fields from the submission.

Comment: Could you please show me how should I move the check? It would help me a lot since I am new to web development

Comment: Ok thanks and also one last question how can I make the php code not open the page again in a new tab?

Comment: Remove the `target="success"` attribute from the form to open in same frame.

Comment: and make it scroll down to the #CmForm?

Comment: Maybe `document.getElementById('CmForm').focus();`